# Need to capture email reply in salesforce

Tags: apex-email-service

I have a certain requirement. I need to capture email reply in Salesforce. Just take a scenario I have sent an email to one contact from **send an email** button from case related list. As soon as I send the mail, Contact will receive mail in his outlook or mailbox . If the contact try to reply over the mail from outlook then will Salesforce  capture this reply automatically? Will we get this email reply somewhere in Salesforce?

Please reply.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 4):

you can use the apex email handler.
if you build a inbound email handler and add the email address that sf will give you in to bcc, then you can easily capture the reply email and attach it to activitiy or whatever you want.
[image: here is the email service]
![here is the email address that you need to add in to bcc][2]

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Implisit](https://www.implisit.com/). Implisit connects to the backend of your email server and your Salesforce and therefore would be able to capture the reply, and can automatically attach it to the right contact record in SF. As a disclaimer, and to be fully transparent, I'm a Product Manager at Implisit.

Answer (score 1):

These are the following steps in order to capture email reply in salesforce

1) Email to case must be activeted in your org
(Customise -> Case -> Email-to-case)
Activate the email to case check box and select the 
When sending email from a case, insert Thread ID in the following sections: option as shown below
and also check the On Demand service checkbox.
[image]

Then thread id is appended in subject of the email send to the user.
So when the user replied to that mail it is automatically added in Email related list of the case.

Thread id = Organisation id + case id.
So thread id represents from which organisation and the case the mail is generated.
For future reference please follow the below link:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizesupport_ondemand_email_to_case.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Hi Monish, 
Thanks for your reply. This is Email-to-case functionality and for that we need to send email from my mailbox and case will get create in Salesforce. For my case, I will need to send email by clicking "Send an email" button from emails related list in case. Please provide suggestion if you have any related to this.

Thanks, Vivek

Comment: @VivekChouhan - The above will work when sending emails from the case object in salesforce

Comment: @Eric   Hey Eric, I tried with this. I sent email from case object. I am also getting thread in email subject and body but while replying it is not coming in related list. Does Email-to-case work if I initiate emailing from "send an email" button? Can you please let me know if I am missing some thing here. Thanks, Vivek

Comment: Try reviewing this: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176597&language=en_US

Comment: @Eric: will email-to-case work if I create a case manually and then send an email from email related list ? will it maintain email chain in related list? Please suggest.